# java ScheduledExecutorService giving weird results

Tags: java, java-8, scheduledexecutorservice

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test implements Runnable {

    private Integer xyz = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

        Test test = new Test();
        test.xyz = 20;

        Test test2 = new Test();

        System.out.println("Values of xyz = " + test.xyz + " , " + test2.xyz);

        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(test, 100, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(test2, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executorService.awaitTermination(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.xyz += (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + this.xyz);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Values of xyz = 
20 1  | 
10 30 | 
11 12 | 
11 23 | 
11 34 | 
11 45 | 
11 56 | 
11 67 | 
11 78 | 
11 89 | 
11 100 | 
11 111 | 
10 40 | 
11 122 | 
11 133 | 
11 144 | 
11 155 | 
11 166 | 
11 177 | 
11 188 | 
11 199 | 
11 210 | 
11 221 | 
10 50 | 
11 232 | 
11 243 | 
11 254 | 
11 265 | 
10 275 |   (10 should have been 60 here)
10 285 | 
10 295 | 
10 305 | 
10 315 |
```

Comment: `test` runs 3 times and `test2` is executed on 2 different threads. There's nothing very surprising there. Why did you expect 60?

Comment: I was missing some context about ScheduledExecutorService, I thought no. of tasks are equal to no. of threadPool size. Didn't know they are executed in multiple threads to meet up rate requirements.
-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ScheduledExecutorService uses thread allocated to run the submitted task at the rate specified. The misunderstanding was that each thread is associated with 1 task and is only used to run that particular task at the frequency specified. But that is not the case, so it makes sense.